# TableLayoutPanel: How can i navigate with tab key through dynamically added controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a form which contains a dynamically added TableLayoutPanel, which contains some dynamically added Labels, TextBox, CheckBox. I am obtaining exactly the visualization I would like to have, but I am struggling to get the "tab key" to work for moving from one control to the other.
I have tried to add a:

```
control.TabIndex = tabIndex++;
control.TabStop = true;
```

But this doesn't seem to have any impact...

This is the (tested) stub code:

```
class MyForm : Form
    {
    public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] titles = {"first","second"};
            var myLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            myLayout.AutoSize = true;
            int myTabIndex = 1; //Not really necessary
            int rowNumber = 0;

            foreach (var title in titles)
            {
                var label = new Label();
                label.Text = title;
                myLayout.Controls.Add(label, 0, rowNumber);
                var control = new TextBox();
                control.TabIndex = myTabIndex++; //Not really necessary
                myLayout.Controls.Add(control, 1, rowNumber);
                rowNumber++;
            }
            this.Controls.Add(myLayout);
        }
    }
```

This is the window I get, and I am not able to navigate from first to second field using the tab key.

[image: Simple TableLayourPanel form]

---

**Update:**
Applying [Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129) did not help.

Comment: I tested your code and it works properly. It switches between 2 textboxes using tab. May be a silly question, but Does your Tab key work?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for testing the code! My tab key does work :), now I wonder if it's something with my form configuration...

Comment: Your code works also for me.

Comment: @Pearson I can only confirm that for me it doesn't work...

Comment: Does your first control have the focus?

Comment: @Pearson My prompt starts is in the first box, and I am able to type text inside it, but I can only move to the next box by using the mouse...

Comment: Does it works, if you create a new WindowsFormsApplication with only two TextBoxes? (with Windows Forms Designer)

Comment: @Pearson I cannot test right now. I am installing [Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129) and hoping for the best...

Comment: That snippet you posted works.  Try it yourself in a new project.

Comment: @LarsTech Yep, in a totally new project, it works. Now I have to understand why... It's because the form is autoresizing? It's because the form is actually created from a main window clicking on a button? I'll have to try several things! Note: the tabIndex setting doesn't even seem to be necessary.

Comment: I struggle to understand the reason of downvoting... This is a problem that could happen to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have been corrupted in my project. The best I could do is to move on with a new clean Windows Form project, and everything now is working.
[image]